# Can enumerate be used in recursion? What would be the recursion of this example?

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, enumeration

Example with a for-loop for finding the smallest number and its position:

```
def smallest(list):
     smallest = 1000000
     smallestposition=-1
     for pos,value in enumerate(list):
         if(value < smallest):
             smallest = value
             smallestposition = pos
     return smallest,smallestposition
print smallest([23,444,222,111,56,7,45])
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no point of using `enumerate()` into a recursive function, as enumering is iterating, which is the "contrary" of recursion.

A recursive version of this function could be:

```
def smallest(lst, idx=0):
    s = (lst[idx], idx)
    if idx == len(lst) - 1:
        return s
    return min(s, smallest(lst, idx + 1))
```